# Fortran program sometimes hangs while writing large files to disk

Tags: file-io, fortran, large-files

I have written a meshing application that runs quite well except for one thing:
While writing the results to disk, the program *sometimes* hangs. Well effectively it is still running, I can see it produces 100% CPU load and occupying memory using top. But there is no new data written to the file and this state would probably last indefinitely.
The job can not even be killed, the only option I had so far was rebooting the machine to get rid of the job.

However, most of the time the *exact same* job executes until the end without any problems. It should be noted that this only happens for large jobs where the final file size is somewhere above the order of 50GB. I haven't hat this behavior with smaller jobs so far. The result file is written up to a different point each time. Sometimes its 45GB, sometimes its 60GB or something completely different.
The workstation I use operates OpenSuse 13.1, has enough RAM and Disk space available. Yet the same behavior could be observed on different machines.

What I tried so far (apart from the usual debugging) was using Gfortran and Intel Fortran compilers to no avail. I messed around with the -mcmodel=large compiler option, but as I understood this is not related to the size of files written by the program and did not help anything.

I don't know what information to provide since I am really running out of ideas what could be causing the problem. I append the routine that writes an ASCII result file here because it produces the largest file size, but I have the same issues when writing unformatted files with a similar routine.
*ANY* hint on what could possibly cause this behavior is highly appreciated.

```
SUBROUTINE write_legacymesh

use types
use parameters
use data

implicit none

INTEGER :: l, n, i, j, k, number, c, neighbor
REAL(DP), DIMENSION(3) :: pos_d
CHARACTER(LEN=100) :: dummy_char
INTEGER(I4B), DIMENSION(26) :: neighborbuffer
LOGICAL :: file_exists

call write_header
call system ('sync')

! create the mesh file
dummy_char = folder_mesh // '/' // file_mesh
write(*,'(A,A)') ' writing mesh:   ', trim(adjustl(dummy_char))
open(unit=20, file=trim(adjustl(dummy_char)), status='replace', action='write')

! write the mesh file
write(20,'(A)') '  LB database'

l = level_max

! write the header for this mesh size
write(20,'(A)') '  number of collision centers'
write(20,'(I16)') nf(l)
write(20,'(A)') '  number of cut links'
write(20,'(I16)') ncut(l)
write(20,'(A)') '  number of boundary collision centers'
write(20,'(I16)') nb(l)
write(20,'(A)') '  dummy value'
write(20,'(I16)') 0
write(20,'(A)') '  number of inflow boundary collision centers'
write(20,'(I16)') nb1(l)
write(20,'(A)') '  number of pressure boundary collision centers'
write(20,'(I16)') nb2(l)
write(20,'(A)') '  number of slip boundary collision centers'
write(20,'(I16)') nb3(l)
write(20,'(A)') '  number of noslip boundary collision centers'
write(20,'(I16)') nb4(l)
write(20,'(A)') '  lattice spacing'
write(20,'(E16.8)') dx(l)*scaling

! write the coordinates
write(20,'(A)') '              cc       RBT value      cc coordinates'
do n=1, nf(l)

    number = order_level(l)%order(n)
    i = levels(l)%blocks(number)%pos(1)
    j = levels(l)%blocks(number)%pos(2)
    k = levels(l)%blocks(number)%pos(3)

    ! rescale and move the geometry to get the original size and position
    pos_d(1) = (real(i,kind=dp) - 0.5_dp) * dx(l) + corner_ibc(1)
    pos_d(2) = (real(j,kind=dp) - 0.5_dp) * dx(l) + corner_ibc(2)
    pos_d(3) = (real(k,kind=dp) - 0.5_dp) * dx(l) + corner_ibc(3)

    write(20,'(2I16,3E20.7)') n, levels(l)%blocks(number)%state, pos_d*scaling

end do

! write the link info
write(20,'(A)') '  link information'
do n=1, nf(l)

    number = order_level(l)%order(n)
    do c=1, nlinks
        neighbor = levels(l)%blocks(number)%neighbors(c)
        if(neighbor .GT. 0) then
            neighborbuffer(c) = levels(l)%blocks(neighbor)%number
        else
            neighborbuffer(c) = neighbor
        end if
    end do

    write(20,'(7I16)') n, neighborbuffer(1:6)
    write(20,'(A,6I16)') '                ', neighborbuffer(7:12)
    write(20,'(A,6I16)') '                ', neighborbuffer(13:18)

end do

! write the q-values
write(20,'(A)') '  q-values'
do n=1, ncut(l)

    write(20,'(I16,E20.7)') n, max(qmin, min(qmax, aux_level(l)%q_values(n)))

end do

write(20,'(A)') '  end of data'

close(unit=20)
END SUBROUTINE write_legacymesh
```

Edit1: Following the suggestions of flushing write buffers, I added this to every loop that writes data:

```
if(mod(n,10000000) .EQ. 0) then
    call flush(20)
    close(unit=20)
    call system('sync')
    open(unit=20, file=trim(adjustl(dummy_char)), status='old', position='append', action='write')
end if
```

This did not change anything, the routine still hangs at a random point, this time after writing 18.5GB of data or 211'149'016 write events in the first loop.

Edit2: Deactivating buffered I/O with the Intel Fortran compiler (not using the -assume buffered_io flag) kind of "solved" the issue. But of course this leaves me with slow unbuffered writes for large files, a particularly unpleasant combination.

Edit3: Thanks for the suggestion to add manual write buffers. The file format is not well suited to make use of them efficiently, but its still better than nothing. Anyway, this is a legacy file format and I am positive that I can convince my co-workers that a different file format or even unformatted files are the better option.
While I still have no idea what causes the error, at least I have a tolerable way to avoid it now. Thanks for all the valuable suggestions.

Comment: What kind of filesystem do you use? Do you access it directly or over some network?

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me to learn that your program writes so much data so quickly that under certain circumstances the o/s / file-system / what-have-you can't cope and get in a huff.  I'd try breaking the write into chunks, and flush buffers to disk between chunks.  Then I'd switch to using HDF5, but that is another question.

Comment: The File system on the workstation is ext4. I start the program through a SSH session, but the program runs on that workstation and writes to its local file system. What would be the correct procedure to flush the disk buffers with a fortran command?

Comment: Would it be enough to close the file, tell the system to write fs buffers via "call system('sync')" and reopen the file in append mode?

Comment: Flush is done by the FLUSH statement. Place between your write statements. How large are your records or streams in a single write statement?

Comment: The records are very short, a similar routine writes 29 4-Byte integer values per write at most, the writes here are even shorter. From the documentation of flush() I got this: "This does not guarantee that the data is committed to disk". That is why I did not trust it to do what I need in the first place.

Comment: BTW in modern Fortran it is just `flush()` not `call flush()`. The subroutine is a legacy non-standard extension. You can also try the FSYNC subroutine, but who knows.

Comment: The next thing I'd try is rather than flushing chunks is to close the file at the flush point, open another file, write another chunk, close, open another file, ... and at the end `cat` the chunks together.  This would definitely be a workaround but I'm failing so see how else we can help if we confine ourselves to advice on Fortran programming.

Comment: Yeah, unbuffered can be slow. What I normally do I create my own internal buffers and save them as single item. That leads to quite good performance, because I avoid https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/b10932b4-0edd-4e61-89f2-6e478ccba9aa/entry/improving_i_o_performance_in_xl_fortran3?lang=en , but I never got to the file sizes you have and I have large arrays, so the serialization is very simple.